# Is there any to to capture query string and append

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting, http-status-code-404

Is there any to to capture query string and append it to error document (404). Something like requested page : http://www.xyx.com/sdsdsd redirect to : http://www.xyx.com/404.php?pg-name=sdsdsd

I am using this and its working fine

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /404.php?pg-name=$1 [L,R]
```

but the problem is that it is not setting the header to 404 rather setting the header to 302.

I want the header to be 404 i.e "HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found"

Answer (score 0):

change the [L,R] to [L,R=404]

From here: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_r

Comment: no it still doesnt setting the header status to 404

Comment: Try switching it around, so that its [R=404,L,NC]. Also you can force a 404 header on a PHP page by using: header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");

Comment: That header part needs to be in your PHP file itself though, not the htaccess!

Comment: thnx for the quick reply. Yes i did the same thing switch the flag in htaccess, also set the header in php file. nothing worked.

Comment: Weird, the header should definitely have worked in the PHP file, you need to make sure that its the first thing in the file before any output at all is done (even white space like line breaks will count). How are you inspecting the headers? Can you copy & paste the info you're getting back here for us to check?